# I cant seem to pass value from controller to view, Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I can't seem to parse data that i got from db on controller to view, i have tried multiple solutions that i got from similiar question but none seem to work.
i simply want to show my employee list on my admin page.

**Here's my login controller**
The login function works just fine, its just doenst seem to parse the data i got from db to view

```
public function postLogin(Request $request){
        $list = "";
        $list = \DB::table('users')->where('role','1')->get();
        if(Auth::attempt($request -> only('username','password'))){
            if (Auth::user()->role == '0') {
                return view('admin',['daftar' => $list]);
            }else if (Auth::user()->role == '1') {
                return redirect('/EPage');
            }
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

**Here's my admin blade view**

```
<thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">name</th>
          <th scope="col">email</th>
          <th scope="col">phone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          @foreach($list as $lists)
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>{{ $lists->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $lists->email }}</td>
          <td>{{ $lists->phone }}</td>
          @endforeach
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Please help me understand my mistake, Thank you in advance.

i'm expecting the admin page with show user list with role equals to 1

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are telling the view you want a variable named `daftar` to be available not `list` ... on a side note this `postLogin` method seems like it is doing more than just handling a login

Comment: Thx for the warm welcome, indeed i want to register variable "$daftar" on view instead of "$list". as for the postLogin method other than to login, i use it to redirect each user to different view based on their role. the problem is solved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i tinker here and there, i finally found that i forgot to put an "s" on my user(s) table name. silly mistake but crucial hahaha
it seems previously the variable that i parse are actually empty.

Here are my final controller that worked

```
public function postLogin(Request $request){
        if(Auth::attempt($request -> only('username','password'))){
            if (Auth::user()->role == '0') {
                $daftar = \DB::table('users')->where('role',1)->get();
                return view('admin',['daftar' => $daftar]);
            }else if (Auth::user()->role == '1') {
                return redirect('/EPage');
            }
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

and here's my blade view

```
<tbody>
          @foreach($daftar as $lists)
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>{{ $lists->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $lists->email }}</td>
          <td>{{ $lists->Phone }}</td>
        </tr>
          @endforeach
      </tbody>
```

also thanks to waqar for correcting my previous mistakes

Answer (score 0):

You can send list data with view using **compact** like:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request){
    $list = "";
    $list = \DB::table('users')->where('role','1')->get();
    if(Auth::attempt($request -> only('username','password'))){
        if (Auth::user()->role == '0') {
            return view('admin',compact('list'));
        }else if (Auth::user()->role == '1') {
            return redirect('/EPage');
        }
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

then you can use **$list** on your blade easily.